# Seating six people at a round table, permutation question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there of seating six people at a round table so that two specific people sit together?

I think it is a permuation question but not 100% sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

Circular table questions, you can designate one person as "special" and sit them first and arrange everyone else around that person.

"Where a specific group of people must sit together" questions, you can relabel those people as a single unit and then once having arranged everyone else, then having the people in the unit move around in their spot.

---

For your specific question, you have persons A,B,C,D,E,F.  Suppose E and F must sit together.  Let them be called X instead.  How many ways can you arrange persons A,B,C,D,X around the table?  Now, remembering that X is two people, how many ways could E,F be arranged where "X" used to be?

Comment: For A,B,C,D,X you can arrange them 5! ways. I'm not sure what you mean for the last part.

Comment: @JonhyHubeetto You can arrange A,B,C,D,X in $5!$ ways **in a line**, but not around a circle.  For arranging around a circle however we consider ABCDX to be the same arrangement as BCDXA as well as CDXAB, DXABC, and XABCD.  So, reiterating what I said earlier, you designate one person as special, say A.  You seat them first, and then arrange the *rest* of the people in the remaining seats.  This removes the difficulty of having to deal with the multiple possible representations for the same event.

Comment: @JonhyHubeetto So, I'll ask again, how many ways can you arrange A,B,C,D,X around a circle?  Now, after having arranged them, decide whether when replacing X by E and F, whether E is on the left or on the right.